# Yarn api get applications by elapsedTime

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Is there an easy way to query the yarn applications api to get applications which have run for more than x amount of time?

Following url gives a list of apps, but doesn't look like it respects the elapsedTime parameter

`http://<RM_DOMAIN>:<RM_PORT>/ws/v1/cluster/apps?states=RUNNING&elapsedTime=200000`

Answer (score 1):

`elapsedTime` is not a supported Query Parameter.
You can use `jq` to filter the apps that match the criteria.

```
curl http://<RM_DOMAIN>:<RM_PORT>/ws/v1/cluster/apps?states=RUNNING | jq '.apps.app[]| select(.elapsedTime > 200000)'
```

Or you can use `startedTimeBegin` parameter, to get all the apps with start time beginning with this time (ms since epoch). For example,

```
curl http://<RM_DOMAIN>:<RM_PORT>/ws/v1/cluster/apps?states=RUNNING&startedTimeBegin=1492968581437
```

Comment: My use-case is to fetch all the application ID's which have run in the last 1 week using State=Finished. So Can we use > for startedTimeBegin?