# How can I list active DISTCP jobs?

Tags: hadoop, jobs, distcp

How can I list active DISTCP jobs?

I'm running a distcp job between two clusters.
`hadoop distcp hdfs://x/y /x/y`

I want to run this continually but need to make sure existing `distcp` tasks are complete.

I've tried the following on both source and destination clusters, but I cannot see the copy operation.
 `mapred job -list all`

Comment: You are using Yarn or Hadoop V1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a variation on [Yarn api get applications by elapsedTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552215/yarn-api-get-applications-by-elapsedtime).  In your case you can use the RM Cluster Applications API to get all the apps (unfortunately it doesn't filter on `name`), then filter the apps where name equals `distcp`.  The following shows how to filter using jq:

```
$ curl 'RMURL/ws/v1/cluster/apps' | jq '.apps.app[] | select (.name == "distcp")'
```

For your case, if you're only interested in active jobs you would add the `states` filter to the API call.

```
$ curl 'RMURL/ws/v1/cluster/apps?states=NEW,NEW_SAVING,SUBMITTED,ACCEPTED,RUNNING' |\
    jq '.apps.app[] | select (.name == "distcp")'
```

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Applications_API